# Font imported in an Angular app (SCSS) does not load on other devices

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, cross-browser, google-webfonts

I've used two fonts throughout the entire application: Bebas Neue and Nunito.
I imported these fonts with @import statements in the styles.scss file in the app directory.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:700&display=swap');
```

And then used them in individual component.scss with font-family

```
element {
   font-family: "Bebas Neue";
}
```

And similarliy for the other font as well.

This worked perfeclty fine during development. After the production build, the app still displayed the fonts correctly on my device, **but they do not load on other devices at all.**
This might look like a duplicate of another question, but I could not find a solution to this problem specifically.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use it implement like this.

Copy paste the below code in your `index.html` file in your projects `src` directory like given below inside `<head>` tag

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. But why didn't the @import statement work earlier  in the scss file? Is that an 'ng build --prod' bug?

Comment: It works but `ng build --prod` converts your whole project into smaller bundle files. It may work in development mode but it's not a good practice. You can use @import statement to load other css/scss libraries or frameworks like bootstrap. But always fonts should be loaded in the project using their reference link and adding them to your  `index.html` file.